# Send byte from PC to USB communication port using java

Tags: java, usb, communication

Can I send a byte from PC to usb communication port via java program?
if yes .Is there any sample code that can help in this issue??

I'm looking for sample codes or good tutorials

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Just sending a "byte" on USB would not be useful. Data sent over USB is more complicated than a traditional serial port since multiple devices share the same port. So, what device do you want to send your data to?

Comment: I need to send sequence of bytes .. but for now I want to test how to send data from PC to the PIC using serial communication

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a USB-to-serial converter (which is what it sounds like) then the OS driver software presents a *serial* interface to applications.

I think what you need to look at is the JavaComms API - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html.

Does this page help at all - http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~benres/simpleserial/ ?

Comment: No .. I just want to send data from PC to PIC184550 which is located on a development kit via a USB port

Answer (score 1):

When using a USB-Serial adapter the USB part can (usually) be ignored and instead you should just focus on the serial part. The USB adapter drivers will give you a virtual serial port to use as any other serial port.

For using a serial port with Java see [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) or [Serialio](http://serialio.com/products/serialport/serialport.php)

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified what kind of USB communication you want, so this is going to be a bit generic.

If your device identifies itself as a USB CDC you system probably already loads a driver and enables you to access it as a serial port. Similar is true if the dice identifies itself as a HID (Human Interaction Device) keyboard, mouse etc.

If you have your own type of device, then you can use javax.usb from linux (might be a port for windows). You need to identify your device from the vendor/device id, possibly configure your endpoints, device if you want control, bulk or isochronous data, create the packet, populate it with your byte(s) and then transfer it. Javax.usb has some example code.

For simplicity I'd recommend your device to be a CDC (code available, check google) and it will identify itself as a serial port and you do not need to handle any of the complexity of USB when communicating.